# How to patch imports in a parent class?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, patch

I have something like this:

```
import load_json

class Parent:
    def func_1(self):
         file = load_json("file/path.json")
         file["additional data"] = "some new data"
         return file
```

Child class:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def func_2(self):
        a = self.func_1()
        # do something with a
        return a
```

I want to test func_2, but it relies on func_1 - specifically loading a file. I also want to mock the return json data as there is additional logic in function 2 that (1) I don't want to replicate in the test (2) I also want to test (i.e. if that dependent logic changes, I want this test  to fail).
So, I want to patch that file loading, but I'm not sure how?

I'd assume it's something like this, but this just gives me a "does not gave attribute 'load_json'" error. Any ideas?

```
@patch("path.to.child.load_json", return_value={"my":"file contents"})
def test_func_2():
    c = Child()
    assert c.func_2() == "expected value"
```

Answer (score 0):

okay, running the debugger to see how mock was using that path leads me to:

```
@patch("path.to.parent_file.load_json", return_value={...})
```

Which seems to solve the issue. Not sure how it took so long to work that out, but I assumed if needed to be specified in the scope of the child file import.